# how to make the entity in a solution in a specific order?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

here i hava a `@planningEntity` Entity and a `@planningEntity` Request, this two classes are connected by:

```
public class Request {
    @PlanningListVariable
    private List<Entity> EntityList;
```

and

```
public class Entity{
    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "EntityList")
    private Request Request;
}
```

the solution class is:

```
public class Solution implements Serializable {
    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Request> RequestList;

    @ValueRangeProvider
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Entity> Entities;
```

so what i want in the soultion is a RequestList and every request in the list has a EntityList.

My question is: i want entities in the EntityList of the request are listed by the order of id, but the result is always in a reversed order.

for example, the solution i get is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ9qe.png)

but what i really want is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOWHQ.png)

i tried to add a constraint to limit the order, but it doesnt work.

how can i get what i want? how to set the order?

thank you very much for any ideas.

Comment: The list will stay in whatever order you put them.  You don't say what language this is, but both Java and C# have `sort` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I don't think we make any promises on the order of entities in the best solution in [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/), but still, I can't think of a single piece of code that would actually invert the order.

If you provide a piece of code I can execute to see the issue, I will look into it.

Comment: hi, ive used the code in optaplanner-examples in https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner, if you have that project, you may download the file TaskAssigningHelloWorld.java in https://github.com/yiyiyiyi1999/for_Optaplanner_thing and add it in the folder 'taskAssigning/app'. Then run the main to see the result. ive noticed that in the solution, tasks are listed in a reversed order of its own id. i dont know why and how to configure the order. maybe the order is non-changeable? may the order have something to do with the solving process? thank you so much for further discussion.